# Drop duplicates row in Spark SQL based on custom function on a column in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, drop-duplicates

I am trying to **remove duplicates from my Dataset** in Spark SQL in Java. My dataset has three columns. Let's say the name of the column are `name, timestamp, and score`. The name is the String representation of employee name and timestamp is in long (epoch representation) of the activity that an employee does. The score is the integer filed representing the score of the employee.

Now, Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
Name --> timestamp       -->  scores 
John --> 1595239200000   -->  10  
John --> 1595242800000   -->  10
Bob  --> 1595246400000   -->  20
John --> 1595239200000   -->  10
```

Note that in the above dataset the first and fourth row are the same.

When I use **distinct()** function over the above dataset by doing something like this

```
myDataset.distinct()
```

I get the result as

```
Name --> timestamp       -->  scores 
John --> 1595239200000   -->  10  
John --> 1595242800000   -->  10
Bob  --> 1595246400000   -->  20
```

The fourth row in this case is eliminated which is the expected behaviour.

What I wanted is convert the `timestamp` field into `yyyy-MM-dd` format and then remove duplicates with the combination of Name field. So from the original dataset the first, second and fourth row have the same value of date that is `2020-07-20` for Name = John. I would only want to have one row for the name = 'John'.

So from the above dataset after removing the duplicate row as explained above the resulting dataset would become

```
Name --> timestamp       -->  scores 
John --> 1595239200000   -->  10  
Bob  --> 1595246400000   -->  20
```

Note that I do not have any constraint to keep the first timestamp only for the same name. Any of the timestamp would work for me as long as they all are belonging to the same date.

What I have tried so far is

```
Dataset<Row> duplicateRemovedDataset = myDataset
                .dropDuplicates("Name", String.valueOf(functions.from_unixtime
                        (functions.col("timestamp").divide(1000), "yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

But this is producing me this error

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Cannot resolve column name "from_unixtime((timestamp / 1000), yyyy-MM-dd)" among list of my column name
```

How should I go about doing this?

Or in more general term how to call a custom function while calling `dropDuplicates` on a dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new `column` with date format you need and `drop` duplicates on columns you want as below

**For Java**

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;
Dataset<Row> resultDF = df.withColumn("date", to_date(to_timestamp(df.col("Timestamp").divide(1000)), "yyyy-MM-dd"));

resultDF.dropDuplicates("Name", "date")
        .drop("date")
        .show(false);
```

**For Scala**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val resultDF = df.withColumn("date", to_date(to_timestamp(col("Timestamp") / 1000), "yyyy-MM-dd"))

resultDF.dropDuplicates("Name", "date")
  .drop("date")
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+-----+
|Name|Timestamp    |score|
+----+-------------+-----+
|Bob |1595246400000|20   |
|John|1595239200000|10   |
+----+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: I am not able to find this function `to_timestamp`. Did you mean `from_unixtime` here? Because I already have a timestamp value.

Comment: what version of spark are you using, it's only available since 2.2.0

Comment: I was using 2.1.0. Have upgraded to 2.2.0 and got `to_timestamp` function. But I do not really need to call `to_timestamp` because the column `timestamp` in my example is there in the epoch format. So I would rather call `from_unixtime` on my `timestamp` column. And that would make my thing. Thanks for the idea for adding a column first in the dataset and then do `dropDuplicates` and then drop the added column.

Comment: Ok perfect, `from_timestamp` should work for your case

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val myDataset = Seq(("John","1595239200000",10),           
              ("John", "1595242800000" ,10),
             ("Bob", "1595246400000" ,20),
             ("John", "1595239200000" ,10)
            )
.toDF("Name", "timestamp","score")
myDataset.show()

+----+-------------+-----+
|Name|    timestamp|score|
+----+-------------+-----+
|John|1595239200000|   10|
|John|1595242800000|   10|
| Bob|1595246400000|   20|
|John|1595239200000|   10|
+----+-------------+-----+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, to_date, to_timestamp}

myDataset.withColumn("datestamp",to_date(from_unixtime($"timestamp" / 1000))).dropDuplicates("name","datestamp").show()

+----+-------------+-----+----------+
|name|    timestamp|score| datestamp|
+----+-------------+-----+----------+
| Bob|1595246400000|   20|2020-07-20|
|John|1595239200000|   10|2020-07-20|
+----+-------------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: So the quick answer to your problem is that dropDuplicates operates on existing columns by exact name whereas you were passing a date value.